# "DllAttribute could not be found": call a function in a .jslib file from unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to call a JavaScript Function from a .jslib file in Unity. I did it as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html?_ga=2.180153316.1504142652.1571482865-511052720.1571482865)

I have the .jslibe file in my assets/plugin folder. Now I tried to access it in the following code:

```
public class Prefab : MonoBehaviour
{

    private string test = "test";

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void SendToJavscript(string test);

    void Start()
    {
        SendToJavscript(this.test);

    }
}
```

But it won´t compile and I get the error "The type or namespace name 'DllImportAttribute' could not be found (are you using directive or an assembly reference?)

Has anyone a idea what´s wrong here? I never got this error before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of your script add

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```